# java, regex string not containing a set of word between /

Tags: java, regex

I know this seems a common question, but can't get rid of my problem dispite searching.
I need a regex that matchs only string that doesn't start with a specified set of words and surrounded by /.
Example:

```
/harry/white
/sebastian/red
/tom/black
/tomas/green
```

I don't want strings starting with /harry/ and /tom/, so I expect

```
/harry/white     NO
/sebastian/red   YES
/tom/black       NO
/tomas/green     YES

1) ^/(?!(harry|tom)).*    doesn't match /tomas/green
2) ^/(?!(harry|tom))/.*   matchs nothing
3) ^/((harry|tom))/.*     matchs the opposite
```

What is the right regex? I'd appreciate much if someone explain me why 1 and 2 are wrong.
Please don't blame me :)
Thanks.

Comment: Can the string end in `/` like `/sebastian/red/`

Comment: @abc123 yes, it could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
^(?!/(harry|tom)/).*
```

Why number 1 is wrong: the lookahead should make sure that `harry` or `tom` are followed by a slash.

Why number 2 is wrong: ignore the lookahead; note that the pattern is trying to match two slashes at the start of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the ending *slash* for both of them inside the negative look-ahead, not outside:

```
^/(?!(harry|tom)/).*
```

Not adding a slash, will match `tom` in `tomas`, and the negative look-ahead will not satisfy.